# Recyclerview becoming heavy - Skipped frames

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have infinite scrolling `RecyclerView` with loading more items from API when scrolled to the last item, but after several scrolls my `RecyclerView` starting to lag on adding new items and getting

```
Skipped 197 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

in the logs. I cannot find what is causing the lag.

Followings are my methods

```
 val onLoadMore = object : IOnLoadMore {
        override fun onLoadMore() {
            if (!adapter.loadingMore) {
                adapter.addLoadingItem()
                requestSimple()
            }
        }
    }

fun requestSimple() {
    disposable = MyApplication.apiService.offerSearchWithPromo(
            defaultSharedPreferences.getString(Config.PREF_LANG, Config.RU), request!!)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                adapter.removeLoadingItem()
                adapter.items.addAll(it.offers.data)
                if (it.promotions.data.size > 0) adapter.items.add(it.promotions.data)
                adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.items.size - it.offers.data.size - 1, it.offers.data.size)
                adapter.meta = it.offers.meta
                tv_found.text = resources.getString(R.string.found) + " " + adapter.meta?.pagination?.total.toString()
                if (it.offers.data.size == 15) adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(onLoadMore)
                else adapter.removeListener()
                request!!.page++
            }, {
                showError(it.message.toString())
            })
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
      class AdrResRvDynamic(var context: Context, nestedScrollView: NestedScrollView? = null, var items: MutableList<Any?>) : RVAdrMutableNullable<Any?, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(items) {

        var isLoading: Boolean = false
        var meta: ObjMeta? = null
        private var mIOnLoadMore: IOnLoadMore? = null
        private val VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SIMPLE = 0
        private val VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_VIP = 1
        private val VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SUGGESTED = 2
        private var VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 99
        var loadingMore: Boolean = false

        var curr = ""

    init {
        curr = context.defaultSharedPreferences.getString(Config.PREF_CURRENCY, Config.UZS)

        setHasStableIds(true)
        nestedScrollView?.setOnScrollChangeListener { v: NestedScrollView, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->
            if (v.getChildAt(v.childCount - 1) != null) {
                isLoading = if (scrollY >= v.getChildAt(v.childCount - 1).measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight && scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    if (mIOnLoadMore != null) mIOnLoadMore!!.onLoadMore()
                    true
                } else false
            }
        }
    }

    fun setOnLoadMoreListener(mIOnLoadMore: IOnLoadMore) {
        this.mIOnLoadMore = mIOnLoadMore
    }

    fun removeListener() {
        this.mIOnLoadMore = null
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            items[position] == null -> VIEW_TYPE_LOADING
            items[position]!!::class.simpleName == "ObjAuto" -> VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SIMPLE
            items[position]!!::class.simpleName == "ObjAutoVip" -> VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_VIP
            items[position] is List<*> -> VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SUGGESTED
            else -> VIEW_TYPE_LOADING
        }
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val obj = items[position]
        when (holder) {
            is ItemViewAutoCard -> holder.bind(obj!! as ObjAuto)
            is ItemViewAutoCardSUGGESTED -> holder.bind(obj!! as List<ObjAuto>)
            is ItemViewAutoCardVIP -> holder.bind(obj!! as ObjAutoVip)
            is ItemViewLoadingMore -> {
//                holder.itemView.find<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar1).isIndeterminate = true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SIMPLE -> ItemViewAutoCard(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.li_auto_card, parent, false))
            VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_VIP -> ItemViewAutoCardVIP(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.li_auto_card_vip, parent, false))
            VIEW_TYPE_AUTO_SUGGESTED -> ItemViewAutoCardSUGGESTED(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.li_auto_card_suggested, parent, false))
            else -> ItemViewLoadingMore(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.progress_bar_load_more, parent, false))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun removeLoadingItem() {
        loadingMore = false

        if (items.size == 0) return
        items.removeAt(items.size - 1)
        notifyItemRemoved(items.size)
    }

    fun addLoadingItem() {
        loadingMore = true
        items.add(null)
        notifyItemInserted(items.size - 1)
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    }
}
```

PS: I've commented out all the logic inside my ItemViews so there's nothing going on in `onBind()` method, i'm just showing empty layout, but still after several loads the recycler becoming laggy.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, The problem was placing `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`. I needed it because there was a view above `RecyclerView` which needed to be scrolled. I've removed it and put it as a first item in my `RecyclerView`. What was happening is that the items in `RecyclerView` was not being recycled as its height was just expanding.

Verdict: Never put `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Same issue is happening with me. if I remove nestedscrollview then recyclerview smoothly work but if i put same recyclerview inside nestedscrollview and do pagination recyclerview starting to lag and app also crash showing out of memory error due to this but I need to put my recyclerview inside nestedscrollview. Can you please tell how can I fix that without removing nestedscrollview?

Comment: then you can try making your recyclerview height fixed, and handle your scroll dispatch yourself. For example you can detect the scroll to bottom of your nestedscrollview and when reached stop listening to scroll from nestedScroll and listen to scroll from recyclerview, but it's a bit hard. I think the better way is keeping your recyclerview in nonScrollable view and adding needed views as different viewholders ...as header or footer...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is solved and is an old question. Just in case someone else is facing a similar issue due to a different cause.

In my case, the issue was that I was trying to Format a currency amount in recyclerview item binding.

I fixed it by formatting the currency before passing the data to the recyclerview and offloading the process to a coroutine instead of the main thread.